# Javascript fade or crossfade background images

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image, fade

Is it possible to fade in / crossfade background images please?

If so, how...

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A great way to do these type of effects is with jQuery.

Please take a look at:
http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/ 
http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

The sites provide a good example of how to do each, simply apply it to your background images.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, Jamie and thank you. Question is, will that work on background images rather than <img> tags?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Notice in the sample codes, the html elements are referred to by their ids in jQuery. So, #someid, can reference anything (div, table, span) as long as it uses #someid. Remember now, HTML best practices mean that ids are unique, so using multiple ids will clash and the jQuery won't work. If you want your jQuery code to affect multiple divs, you can use classes, so rather than #someid, you can use .someclass in the jQuery code.

Comment: I'm sorry but this answer isn't really true. You can fade out an element that has a background image but it's not the same as fading out the background image itself.

Answer (score 2):

No.
Nesting a bunch of objects, or stacking them with absolute positioning is typically the only way to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 1):

Not unless you're operating on a container (etc) that has a background image set, no.  You may want to consider changing "crossfading the background of a single element" to "changing the opacities of more than one container, each of which having their own background image" - that's a more realistic approach with JS.

Answer (score 0):

I'll hazard a guess and go with 'yes'.